# lock creation in python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

When I read the documentation, it seems the lock object is mentioned in both `threading` and 
`thread` library, so I found there are 2 ways to create a lock: `threading.Lock()` and `thread.allocate_lock()`, and the return values are both of type `thread.lock`.

```
>>> a = thread.allocate_lock()
>>> b = threading.Lock()
>>> a
<thread.lock object at 0x1002ab190>
>>> b
<thread.lock object at 0x1002ab0f0>
```

I wonder if there's any difference between these 2 creation methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html) itself recommends the `threading` module.

> Note
>   The thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3.0. The 2to3 tool will
>   automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0; however, you 
>   should consider using the high-level threading module instead.

The `threading` module lays on top of the `thread` module, as stated in the [threading docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html)

> This module constructs higher-level threading interfaces on top of the lower level 
>   thread module. See also the mutex and Queue modules.

So one would assume that the locks they use are very close to identical, but the `threading` module wraps the `thread` modules calls.

Indeed later in the [threading docs](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html), it states:

> A primitive lock is a synchronization primitive that is not owned by a particular
>   thread when locked. In Python, it is currently the lowest level synchronization
>   primitive available, implemented directly by the thread extension module.

So in summary, they are most likely identical, and python itself recommends the `threading` module. So use that if you are in doubt.